# How can I run a binary process using ansible module?

Tags: python-3.x, ansible

I am writing an ansible module to run a custom binary. To get the custom binary, we need to download the installer. On running installer_binary, it creates a folder, and runs another binary as process.
e.g: `./installer_binary ---> testfolder/testbinary --config test.config`

Here's my code:
In modules:
run_binary.py

```py
def add(self):
   filename = "installer.bin"
   installer_file = self.download_binary_file(url,filename)
   self.module.run_command(chmod +x installer_file)
   self.module.run_command('./' + installer_file)

def download_file(self,url,local_filename):
        # NOTE the stream=True parameter below
        with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
            r.raise_for_status()
            with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
                for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192): 
                    # If you have chunk encoded response uncomment if
                    # and set chunk_size parameter to None.
                    #if chunk: 
                    f.write(chunk)
        return local_filename
```

playbook.yml

```yaml
- name: Add Collector
  hosts: host1
  become: true
  become_user: ubuntu
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
   - name: Running module
     test:
      action: run_binary
```

On running the above playbook, the file is getting extracted, but the testbinary is not running.

When I am run the installer_binary directly on the machine, it is working fine, and running the binary as process.

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml
```

host1: Ubuntu machine

Comment: `self.module.run_command(chmod +x installer_file)`, with the `chmod` command unquoted looks dubious to me. `self.module.run_command('chmod +x installer_file')`, would look more accurate.

Comment: cmd = "chmod +x " + installer_file
 self.module.run_command(cmd) 
This is the actual code. I check on the remote machine, file is becoming executable.